# How to change buffering of an already-opened stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

Searching for answers, I keep getting advice on how to specify the buffering, when *opening* the file.

However, I need to change the buffering of an already-opened stream (such as `sys.stdout`). How to do that?